# Custom calendar system support in Exchange OWA

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, exchange-2010, localization

Since Exchange doesn't provide support for all calendar types in OWA, I need to create one, using Microsoft.Net's support of calendars, but where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "all calendar types". However, the Exchange Web Services (EWS) API is what you'll want to use. In particular, the EWS managed API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749(EXCHG.80).aspx) will probably be the easiest and simplest way for you to get started with custom client development.

Comment: Thanks, glad somebody noticed my question, I'll give it a try!